# Почему на моем сайте при проверке lighthouse сильно падает число в производительности?

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, pagespeed-insights, pagespeed

Почему на моем сайте при проверке lighthouse сильно падает число в производительности с 95 до 72 если юзаю WP плагин пагинизации WP-Paginate.  Если плагин отключаю то всю норм. Юзаю W3totalcache для оптимизации.
Ума не приложу как оптимизировать плагин WP-Paginate чтоб в lighhouse всё норм было. Лайтхаус в отчёте не дат никаких данных по js или css этого плагина которые мещают.

Вот отчет лайтхауса: https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-transscreen-ru/hggak8ji3c?hl=ru&form_factor=desktop
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]